# Perl web service on Windows crashes when running system commands in parallel

Tags: perl, psgi

I am modernising a Perl-based system for a client.  This system runs on Windows (Strawberry Perl), connects to a database, and calls some scripts, which in turn run other programs.

My first thought is to write a PSGI application and trigger the application using curl.  My initial experiments seem to be working, although only using the Twiggy server. (Thrall leaks memory badly, and forking servers like Starman don't work on Windows.)

I'd like to improve the system further by running the other external commands in parallel. I've tried using AnyEvent or Parallel::ForkManager. It works for standalone scripts, but when running inside of Twiggy, Perl crashes.

My question is: how can I execute external commands in parallel so that Twiggy (or an alternative server, if this is an issue with Twiggy) so that it doesn't crash?

Comment: I highly recommend [Mojo::Server::PSGI](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::Server::PSGI)

Comment: I'm having a problem with software crashing, and would like to know about similar software that doesn't crash. What's wrong with asking about alternative libraries?

Comment: I've edited it to remove the explicit request for library recommendations.

Comment: Then edit the title as well.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I've edited the question and title. Can it be removed from hold, please.